# Build strategies for utilizing npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

This must be a commonly solved problem, but I cannot find a whole lot on Google/SO so far.

When we run `npm install` and fetch say 50+ packages including devDependencies as well as runtime dependencies, npm creates `node_modules` (if needed) and adds each of those packages inside that folder.  This means we end up with thousands of extraneous files included under `node_modules`.  Each of those packages contains their own package.json, README.md, minified files, source files, etc. Our application really only cares about jquery.js (for DEV) and jquery.min.js (for PROD), so it seems to be a waste to include all of these other files into our build and therefore our web server.

Is there a standard when it comes to handle these `npm` packages in a way so that we simply expose ONLY the necessary files to the user?  I imagine many people have this kind of issue but I don't see any built in npm constructs that allow us to do this easily.

See below.. the yellow highlighted files are the only files we really care about in Production, but we get all these extra files as well including the source code.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: We currently use webpack but we typically just bundle our business logic that is ES6 and use babel to transpile it into ES5. Is there built in support for doing this with npm packages/bower packages/etc without using a "master" list to tell webpack what files to grab?

Comment: Yes, you `require` dependencies just like you do in node.  eg `var $ = require('jquery')`.  webpack finds the appropriate jquery file and bundles it in.

Comment: Ok so I think the fundamental issue here is that my company has not completely converted to using ES6 everywhere. We only have a small subset of our code on those newer technologies so there is no way to just start using it out of the box without updating all of our code to use require() or import statements

Comment: @josh3736 how does webpack know whether to bundle jquery.js or jquery.min.js? Does it always use jquery.js and then we are responsible for minifying it when needed?

Comment: It uses `main` in package.json, which for jquery is dist/jquery.js.  Presumably you're already have webpack configured to minify your own code for production, so jquery's full build would likewise be minified.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense then. I think my biggest misunderstanding is around the fact that we are using a combination of old and new technologies and practices. This will all be much more apparent once we can get our entire code base onto ES6. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common solution consist of bundling your application on a different machine and then expose the built artefacts on production server.

There are a lot of great JS bundlers out there. The ones I have personally used are [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), and [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). All amazing tools.

The main idea consists of writing your application in a Node environment and then bundle it to make it readable to the browser.

For simpler projects I find Browserify a very good compromise between power and ease of configuration. But it's a matter of taste, at the end. :)

Comment: Today we do build and deploy from a Jenkins node. its a matter of "how to build" these properly as we don't want to have some "master" list of all the npm packages we need to copy over as a build artifact that has to get updated every time 1) we change our dependencies or 2) the folder structure of an npm package changes and breaks the build. Does that make sense?

Comment: so we already use webpack so I would like to use that if possible. However, the first change we would have to make is currently all our business logic is bundled using webpack but our npm packages like jquery are all pulled in using traditional `<script>` tags in HTML. We would 1) have to change to use bundles for all our code and 2) how does webpack know specifically what files to grab during different builds? i.e. grab jquery.js in test deployments and grab jquery.min.js during production?

Comment: You should just import the non-minified version in both cases and setup a build routine to minify your JS code. How to make Jquery available it's up to you, you can require it in your code are make it globally available with proper Weback config.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the package.json file and remove all the unnecessary dependencies then do

`npm install --save`

By doing this, it will create a local `node_modules` folder and only download the necessary packages into it (not the global `node_modules` folder)

Keep in mind, by default, node checks for local `node_modules` folder. If it couldn't find it, it will use the global folder.

Also, you don't expose all the packages in the `node_modules` folder. In fact, they will not be used unless you `require();` them in the node.js file

**EDIT:**

For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

So `jquery module` do things a bit differently behind the scene for node.js comparing to the regular front-end jquery.

It requires `jsdom` so you will have to download that as well from here https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Comment: So my packages are scoped to just my local repository, but what I'm saying is if you run `npm install jquery` you will install like 200 files (source files, readme files, package.json files, etc) when all you need is jquery.js and jquery.min.js. Get what I mean?

Comment: see my edit, i have included a screenshot of what `jquery` looks like when installed via `npm`. The yellow highlighted files are the only files I care about once we release to an environment but we have extraneous files.

Comment: @MattHintzke Oh I see. I'm updating my answer now

Comment: Sorry I don't think my use case is obvious here, but I am not trying to use jQuery inside of nodejs or do anything fancy. I am trying to simply take the scripts required on my website and have them get built in a way where a client can access them at `https://mywebsite.com/js/<package>/<package>.js` like `/js/jquery/jquery.js` if we deployed to a test env or `/js/jquery/jquery.min.js` if deployed to a prod env.  Right now, as you can see from the screen shot, every npm package may use its own folder structure to expose its files which is not ideal for the application.

Comment: @MattHintzke, I just want to make sure we're on the same page. You want to use different files based on the environment?

Comment: I mean thats what npm appears to encourage, right? These packages provide use both version and we can choose to either 1) select the one we want based off env and only include that in the build or 2) Always select the non-minified one and then later on use webpack/grunt/gulp to minify it based off that same env variable.  I guess the question is what is more common practice

Answer (score 0):

Base on what I read about [npm install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) I do not think there is a option to manipulate the installation in the way you want. The packages will install the way the package author decides to package it, sometimes minified sometimes not.

Having said that, you should look for third party [solutions like modclean](https://github.com/ModClean/modclean) which does exactly what you want post package installation. Run this command in the root of your project directory

```
npm install modclean -g
modclean
```

As long as your test coverage is good, ModClean would be perfect for your need.